# Xen 4.2 on CentOs 6.3 : can't compile a libvirt 0.9.10 xen-activated?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I followed that tutorial for Xen 4.2 on CentOs 6.3. http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-xen-on-centos-6.3-x86_64-paravirtualization-and-hardware-virtualization

When building a new libvirt package with `rpmbuild -bb libvirt.spec`

I get that error :

```
 CC     libvirt_driver_libxl_la-libxl_conf.lo
In file included from libxl/libxl_conf.c:43:
libxl/libxl_conf.h:61: error: field 'ctx' has incomplete type
libxl/libxl_conf.h:80: error: field 'ctx' has incomplete type
libxl/libxl_conf.h:81: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'libxl_waiter'
libxl/libxl_conf.c: In function 'libxlMakeDomCreateInfo':
libxl/libxl_conf.c:365: warning: implicit declaration of function 'libxl_init_create_info' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
libxl/libxl_conf.c:365: warning: nested extern declaration of 'libxl_init_create_info' [-Wnested-externs]
libxl/libxl_conf.c:367: error: 'libxl_domain_create_info' has no member named 'hvm'
libxl/libxl_conf.c:383: warning: implicit declaration of function 'libxl_domain_create_info_destroy' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
libxl/libxl_conf.c:383: warning: nested extern declaration of 'libxl_domain_create_info_destroy' [-Wnested-externs]
libxl/libxl_conf.c: In function 'libxlMakeDomBuildInfo':
libxl/libxl_conf.c:406: warning: implicit declaration of function 'libxl_init_build_info' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
libxl/libxl_conf.c:406: warning: nested extern declaration of 'libxl_init_build_info' [-Wnested-externs]
libxl/libxl_conf.c:408: error: 'libxl_domain_build_info' has no member named 'hvm'
[...]
```

Do you know what I need to install or change to pass that step?

Comment: Did you fix/get this to work? I'm having the same issue..

Comment: Unfortunately no... but I made by pci passthrough working with Kvm if this can help you : http://alapointe.degraeve.us/post/33244525132/28-simple-steps-to-run-pci-passthrough-in-a-virtual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed here: https://www.crc.id.au/2012/09/20/xen-4-2-0-packages-pushed-to-the-repos/ the current version of libvirt is not compatible with xen 4.2. You may continue with KVM or use Xen 4.2 without libvirt.